# PHP - Validate URL parameter

Tags: php

I am trying to get a version number from a URL parameter and validate it to ensure that it is only 6,7 or 8. I have this so far...

```
if(isset($_GET['version'])) {

    if ( in_array($_GET['version'], array('6','7', '8'), true ) ) {
        $version= $_GET['version'];
    } else {
        $version= 'invalid_version';
    }

} else {

    $version= 'missing_version';

}
```

This seems to work correctly, but is it the best way to achieve this? Is there a more robust way of doing it?

Comment: That code is quite direct, explicit, and accurate from my perspective. If you could define "robust" then my opinion might change but as far as defensive programming is concerned, you've hit the nail squarely on the head.

Comment: The only thing you can improve, at least in my opinion, is replacing `isset` with `!empty` because if you type `file.php?version=` now it will say that the version is incorrect, while it actually should be missing. But it is not an essential thing.

Answer (score 2):

So if you by more robust mean more concise you can try this:

```
$versions = [ '6' => 6, '7' => 7, '8' => 8, null => 'missing_version' ];
$version = $versions[$_GET['version']] ?? 'invalid_version';
```

Comment: +1 for a solution, but I would not use it as I do not think that shorter code is always better, for me it would be hard to understand what on earth am I doing here if I looked at this code after a few months.

Comment: i like it nice and tiny, BUT i like it human readable more :D

Comment: There is nothing special about it. Firstly I am creating an array with versions as keys to get it faster. Next I try to access the key of the value `$_GET['version']` and if `$_GET['version']` is not set then it will return null and null key handles the 'missing_version' case. It maybe be also the case that `$_GET['version']` is set but it is not correct value. Then the whole `$versions[$_GET['version']]` will return null but the `??` will override it to `invalid_version`